# ESP-IDF I2C register read with two-byte address

Tags: c, arduino, embedded, esp-idf

I am struggling with swapping from Arduino/Wire library to ESP-IDF's I2C driver. I got stuck at the very first stage, trying to simply read the register.
The function I use is `esp_err_t i2c_master_write_read_device(i2c_port_t i2c_num, uint8_t device_address, const uint8_t* write_buffer, size_t write_size, uint8_t* read_buffer, size_t read_size, TickType_t ticks_to_wait)`.

The problem I face is that my `write_buffer` is uint16_t.

How to get over it?

Thanks

Comment: Does the i2c slave device you're trying to read from have 16-bit addressable registers?  Or are you storing an 8-bit register address in a uint16_t?  It's important to know which.  This info would come from the datasheet on the slave device.

Comment: If a 2-byte register address (which is honestly uncommon except for EEPROMs), you could just do write_size = 2 and pass in the variable or buffer holding your reg address..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass to the function a pointer to the buffer and the size of that buffer.

If you want to write a simple uint16_t variable:

```
uint8_t *write_buffer = (uint8_t*)&old_buffer;
size_t write_size = 2
```

Take into consideration that you are responsible to accomodate the memory for that buffer, so make sure the uint16_t variable is not destroyed before the write function has finished.